# Get the selected text of a web page in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selection, clipboard

I am developing a Google Chrome extension. When a popup is clicked, I would like the input box present in the popup.html file to contain the selected text of the current webpage.

Example textbox:

```
<input id="searchBox" type="text" />
```

When text is selected in a webpage, the textbox should contain the selected word. I tried with `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getSelection()` but it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a thread about this on google groups: [how to get HTML code from selection?](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.dom/browse_thread/thread/7ecbbb066ff2027f)

```
var selection = window.getSelection(); 
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 
if (range) { 
  var div = document.createElement('div'); 
  div.appendChild(range.cloneContents()); 
  alert(div.innerHTML); 
}
```

You can use this in the console or in a plugin, either way.

Answer (score 5):

What youre trying to do requires quite a bit of coding because of Chrome's extreme security precautions.

`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getSelection()` will not work because the "BackgroundPage" is not the current webpage. You need something like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert(window.getSelection().toString());"})
//alerts the selected text
```

However, to transfer that text back to the popup is a long and migraine-causing process. Read 
[Contentscripts and Extension Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) if youre up for the challenge.

Comment: but this plugin https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fbhgckgfljgjkkfngcoeajbgndkeoaaj gets the selection source.

Comment: Yes. It used the same thing i showed you.
Heres the script:

    `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"script.js"});`

And:

    `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    document.getElementById("txtar").innerText=request.viewsource;
    });`

The first part is basically the code i showed you(except in a script file), and the second part is the messaging.

Answer (score 5):

here is another simple solution to get the selected the text in the form of string, you can use this string easily to append a div element child into your code:

```
              var text = '';
              if(window.getSelection){
                text = window.getSelection();
              }else if(document.getSelection){
                text = document.getSelection();
              }else if(document.selection){
                text = document.selection.createRange().text;
              }
              text=text.toString();
```