# Can't get selected text in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm writing a chrome extension , which should be able to do some works with the selected text in the context menu . the code I'm using to get the selected text works in normal cases when I run the code in a normal html page . but when I try to use the same code in my extension , it doesn't return the selected text . here's the code I'm using in my extension to get the selected text :

```
function myClick2(){
  var txt = '';
  if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.getSelection)
    txt = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.getSelection();
  else if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().document.getSelection)
    txt = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().document.getSelection();
  else if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().document.selection)
    txt = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().document.selection.createRange().text;
  console.log("this is the console message");
  console.log("txt: " + txt);
}
```

and here's my manifest and complete complete script file in another link : [Getting text selection in Chrome extension background page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988728/getting-text-selection-in-chrome-extension-background-page)

Comment: I am confused by your use of `getBackgroundPage()`. When would there ever be anything selected on the background page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting text selection in Chrome extension background page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988728/getting-text-selection-in-chrome-extension-background-page)

Comment: Thanks , I've done my research well and I have tried many codes from other questions here , I have also tried to replace "chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()" with "window.getSelection()" but none of them work when I use them as extension though they work well when I use them in a normal html page .